# Mailchimp: Vertically center caption text right of image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, mailchimp

Trying to create a Mailchimp template I am struggling with vertically centering the next inside a predefined layout element.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Aku.png)

Using a table it is possible to center the text in a way that I want but only given the height of the image in pixels which define the height of that row. Setting the table height to 100% has no effect.

Is there any way to - using HTML inside the editor - center this text without requiring any hard coded height?

I am hoping to find a solution without coding the entire element because I doubt I would end up with the same amount of responsivity.